# Can I bomb resources?

Tags: civilization-6

I seem to remember being able to bomb an enemy civilizations resources in Civ 4 (perhaps it is Civ 3). Yet in Civ 5 I am not able to do this. Is it available in Civ 6?

It seems to be quite unrealistic to not be able to bomb an enemies resources. This forces them to protect those resources they need the most.

Edit: Just to clarify I am referring to bombing using Great War Bomber, B17, or Jet Fighter. Not atomic/nuclear weapons.

Comment: Asking 'Why did they (developer) do this?' is off-topic, so I have removed that from your question.

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, what you're talking about is the ability to bombard (range) or bomb (air) tile improvements, which I think was indeed removed with Civ V, only the pillage ability can temporarily wreck improvements.  I'm kinda fuzzy on my Civ IV by now though.

Comment: That is correct. Any chance this has been re-enabled in Civ 6?

Comment: I am fairly certain you can with bombers, not sure about bombarding with siege units and boats though

Answer (score 3):

The answer in short is, in Civ VI, yes they can, but for no yield.

**EDIT:** For more clarification, the resource is set to the same status as pillaged, it produces no additional yield that it's improvement would normally grant you. You can repair the tile with a builder the same as if a land unit pillaged the tile.

- It is worth mentioning that districts that are pillaged must be fixed through production in the city.

> Attributes:
>
> - May Pillage tile improvements and districts (destroying them, but not gaining yields).
> - May perform a Nuclear and Thermonuclear Strike, if your civilization has these weapons.

http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Jet_Bomber_(Civ6)

Comment: I haven't played any civ since IV, but I feel like a little more clarification might help - when you do this, is the resource permanently destroyed, or can they just send a worker to reclaim it after a couple turns?

Comment: All done @Walt - let me know if you want more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pillage districts and improvements with bombers and WMDs - as stated these do not yield pillage rewards. Districts and buildings in the district must be repaired in the city, whereas improvements may be repaired by a builder. It should also be noted that that repairing improvements doesn’t count as a builder use. Additional loss of strategic resources does not impact the attack strength of associated units as in Civ 5 (i.e pillage all iron resources of a civ will not weaken that civs existing swordsman, just prevent them from creating new ones).